Parse a text file into instances of an object
I'm currently working on a university assignment, and I have a problem with parsing text files into instances of an object. A simple explanation of the program I'm working on is a takeaway shop loader. Person inputs a text file with a set format, which is then parsed into instances of an object to create a simple takeaway shop for a user to order and edit their orders. Here is an example of how the text file is formated to work with the code:
Name:JustNom FastFood
Toppings:[<cheese,80>,<pepperoni,120>,<tomato sauce,40>,<ham,150>,<mushroom,80>]
Garnishes:[<cheese,100>,<fried onions, 80>,<bacon,150>]
Pizza:<Name:Margherita,Toppings:[tomato sauce, cheese],Price:500>
Pizza:<Name:Ham and Mushroom,Toppings:[tomato sauce, ham, mushroom, cheese],Price:650>
Burger:<Name:Plain Burger,Garnishes:[],Price:350>
Burger:<Name:Cheese Burger,Garnishes:[cheese],Price:450>

This code here reads each line of the code to essentially remove unnnecessary symbols and words and puts it into it's respective class. I have code that practically does parse the text file, however it only does it for the first part. For example, the cheese and price gets parsed, but not the rest of the toppings.
namespace JustNom.Logic
{
    //The file reader menu that created a menu in which it opens and filters a specific file. 
    internal class FileReaderMenu : MenuItem
    {
        private FileReader _reader;
        public string menuName { get; set; }


        public FileReaderMenu(FileReader reader)
        {
            _reader = reader;
        }

        public override string MenuText()
        {
            return "Select a File.";
        }

        public override void Select()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder($"{MenuText()}{Environment.NewLine}");
            int i = 1;
            foreach (string file in _reader.paths)
            {
                sb.AppendLine($"{i}. {file}");
                i++;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
            int selectedIndex = ConsoleHelpers.GetIntegerInRange(1, _reader.paths.Count, MenuText()) - 1;
            string[] result = File.ReadAllLines(_reader.paths[selectedIndex]);
            if (result.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cannot open file - No data found");
            }
            else if (result.Length > 0) 
            {
                var splitedStringList = new List<List<String>>();
                
                Menu menu = new Menu(menuName);

                foreach (string file in result)
                {
                    if (file.StartsWith("Name:"))
                    {
                        menuName = file.Substring("Name:".Length);

                    }
                    string token = file.Substring(0, file.IndexOf(':'));
                    switch (token)
                    {
                        case "Toppings":
                            Topping topping = LoadToppings(file);
                            menu.AddToppings(topping);
                            break;
                        case "Garnishes":
                            Garnish garnish = LoadGarnishes(file);
                          
                            menu.AddGarnish(garnish);

                            break;
                        case "Pizza":
                            Pizza pizza = LoadPizzas(file);
                            menu.AddPizza(pizza);
                            break;
                        case "Burger":
                            Burger burger = LoadBurgers(file);
                            menu.AddBurger(burger);
                            break;


                    }

                    static Topping LoadToppings(string toppings)
                    {
                        int startIndex = toppings.IndexOf('<') + 1;
                        int endIndex = toppings.IndexOf(',');
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string name = toppings.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
                        endIndex = toppings.IndexOf('>');
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string price = toppings.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        return new Topping(name, price);
                    }

                    static Garnish LoadGarnishes(string garnishes)
                    {
                        int startIndex = garnishes.IndexOf('<') + 1;
                        int endIndex = garnishes.IndexOf(',');
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string name = garnishes.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
                        endIndex = garnishes.IndexOf('>');
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string price = garnishes.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        return new Garnish(name, price);
                    }

                    static Pizza LoadPizzas(string pizza)
                    {
                        int startIndex = pizza.IndexOf(':') + 7;
                        int endIndex = pizza.IndexOf(',');
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string name = pizza.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = endIndex + 11;
                        endIndex = pizza.IndexOf("]");
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string toppings = pizza.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = endIndex + 1;
                        endIndex = pizza.IndexOf(">");
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string price = pizza.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        return new Pizza(name,toppings, price);
                    }

                    static Burger LoadBurgers(string burger)
                    {
                        int startIndex = burger.IndexOf(":") + 7;
                        int endIndex = burger.IndexOf(",");
                        int length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string name = burger.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = burger.IndexOf('[');
                        endIndex = burger.IndexOf("]");
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;
                        
                        string garnish = burger.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        startIndex = burger.IndexOf(':');
                        endIndex = burger.IndexOf(">");
                        length = endIndex - startIndex;

                        string price = burger.Substring(startIndex, length);

                        return new Burger(name,garnish, price);
                    }

                }
                OrderMenuItem OrderMenu = new OrderMenuItem(menu);
                OrderMenu.MenuText();
            }
        }
    }
}

namespace JustNom.JustNom
{
    internal class Menu
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        private List<Burger> _burgers;
        private List<Pizza> _pizzas;
        private List<Garnish> _garnish;
        private List<Topping> _topping;

        public IEnumerable<Burger> Burgers { get { return _burgers; } }

        public IEnumerable<Pizza> Pizzas { get { return _pizzas; } }

        public IEnumerable<Garnish> Garnish { get { return _garnish; } }

        public IEnumerable<Topping> Toppings { get { return _topping; } }

        public Menu(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
            _burgers = new List<Burger>();
            _pizzas = new List<Pizza>();
            _topping = new List<Topping>();
            _garnish = new List<Garnish>();
        }

        public void AddBurger(Burger burger)
        {
            _burgers.Add(burger);
        }

        public void AddPizza(Pizza pizza)
        {
            _pizzas.Add(pizza);
        }

        public void AddGarnish(Garnish garnish)
        {
            _garnish.Add(garnish);
        }

        public void AddToppings(Topping topping)
        {
            _topping.Add(topping);
        }
    }
}

This class contains all the objects that has all the parsed objects in. Sorry for a long winded description, I'm trying to add as much description that I can as there's a lot of code in this project. Please let me know if there's any other class you'd like to see to help you understand my question more!
I tried looping the Load() methods, however that didn't really work.

The function is named LoadToppings but it parses only one. It needs to consume the rest of the line until there is no topping left to parse. And if it works there, you can adapt it for the others.

I'm not really sure how I could add that to the function. That's one of the main issues I have with my functions. Splitting the string into an array maybe but i'm not too sure

Just looking at the first problem you mentioned, you've written the LoadToppings method to only process the first topping. I'll give an example here of one way to fix this.
I modified the return value of LoadToppings to return a List<Topping> instead of a single topping, so we can process all the toppings at once.
First we can grab the string between the [ and ] characters, which contains all the topping pairs (Name and price).
Next, we can split that string on the < and > characters, so we end up with a list of strings which each contain only the internal pair of topping Name and Price for a topping.
Then we can split each of these on the comma and use them to create a Topping, which we add to a List<Toppings>, and which is returned at the end:
List<Topping> LoadToppings(string input)
{
    var toppings = new List<Topping>();
    if (input == null) return toppings;

    if (input.Contains("["))
    {
        int start = input.IndexOf("[") + 1;
        int end = input.IndexOf("]", start);

        if (start < end)
        {
            var toppingStrings = input.Substring(start, end - start);

            // Now split on "<>" to get the individual topping
            // items, like: "cheese,80", "pepperoni,120", etc.
            var toppingPairs = toppingStrings.Split(new[] { '<', '>' }, 
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            foreach(var toppingPair in toppingPairs)
            {
                var parts = toppingPair.Split(',', 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                if (parts.Length == 0) continue;

                Topping topping = new Topping { Name = parts[0] };

                if (parts.Length > 1 &&
                    decimal.TryParse(parts[1], out decimal price))
                {
                    topping.Price = price;
                }

                toppings.Add(topping);
            }
        }
    }

    return toppings;     
}


I tried adding this, but it completely messes up my switch statement and causes a lot of errors. this is due to the fact that my switch statement expects the end result to be a string that gets added to the topping class list.

Yes,  that will need to change.

It looks to me like it expects a Topping to be returned, not a string. But couldn't you just change that to something like case "Toppings": List<Topping> toppings = LoadToppings(file); foreach(Topping topping in toppings) menu.AddToppings(topping); break;
